# Install Open-vmtools for Ubuntu 14.04 without internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esx

I don't use Ubuntu so much and I hate it when things change at every version.
Now The procedure I always used to install vmtools on an ESX seems *old* and pushes you to install the Open-vmtools.

..Which I am not able to find anywhere.

I'm using an ESX 5.5 and Ubuntu 14.04.03 lts.

The link to download the package seems not updated, I mean.. I can not find the package for "Trusty Tahr"
Link: [Packages for esx](http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/index.html)

And this doesn't help at all: [Instructions](http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/Ubuntu_14_04_LTS.html)

For `packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/admin/open-vm-tools`, just like the others.. I need an Internet connection: useless for my case..

Anybody who was able to install the Open vm tools? Are these ones really better or I'm good to go with the classical that come with ESX?

Comment: The switch to open-vm-tools is not really new. Anyway, you can just download it to a USB stick and walk it over to the server, like everything else. And if you hate change, you're in the wrong career...

Comment: It is a "armoured machine", no usb, no internet [...] only a cdrom for such updates. and I always used to install vmtools in other machines. Openvm tools though not new I did see them like a plus, not a must. Whatever. I installed vmtools. Microsoft is not the best in the world but at least a new OS come out every few years and the guides are all for the same version. Yes I support changes and improvements, but I also support those who write updated stuff.